# x64 compatible C source

Tags: c, 64-bit, portability, itanium

I think I know what #ifdefs I need to use to be x86-32 and x86-64 compatible on both msvc and gcc, see below. Is this complete for those platforms?

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#  if defined(_M_IA64) || defined(_M_X64)
#    define SIZEOF_SIZE_T 8
#    define SIZEOF_VOIDP  8
#  elif defined(_M_IX86)
#    define SIZEOF_SIZE_T 4
#    define SIZEOF_VOIDP  4
#  else
#    error "Unsupported MSVC platform"
#  endif
#elif defined(__GNUG__)
#  if defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__ia64__)
#    define SIZEOF_SIZE_T 8
#    define SIZEOF_VOIDP  8
#  elif defined(__i386__)
#    define SIZEOF_SIZE_T 4
#    define SIZEOF_VOIDP  4
#  else
#    error "Unsupported GCC platform"
#  endif
#endif
```

Are IA64 and x86 64 the same from a C programmer's perspective?

I'd also like to be able to compile on Macs. What do I add?

**Edit:** I can't use sizeof(), as I'm dealing with untouchable legacy code that use stuff like `#if SIZEOF_VOIDP == SIZEOF_LONG`. I am also only interested in the architectures, not the actual contents. Note that the precompiler does not allow `#if sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(void*)`.

Comment: Why are you #defining constans when, eg `sizeof (void*)` is also a compile time constant?

Comment: Need pre-compile time constant.

Comment: Complete in the sense that I'm covering those two architectures. Also would like to add Mac architectures, whichever those are.

Comment: Warning: See answer below, on Windows x86_64, sizeof(long) == 4 !

Comment: I don't understand why you just can't do `#define SIZEOF_LONG sizeof(long)`?

Comment: For the check you should use #if SIZEOF_VOIDP == SIZEOF_LONG, and not #ifdef.

Comment: Precompiler does not allow #if sizeof(whatever) == sizeof(other).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using your build system to generate these as constants

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf(
      "#if !defined ARCH_MODEL_CONSTANTS_H\n"
      "#define ARCH_MODEL_CONSTANTS_H\n"
      "\n"
      "#    define SIZEOF_LONG  %u\n"
      "#    define SIZEOF_VOIDP %u\n"
      "\n"
      "#endif\n",
      (unsigned)sizeof(long),
      (unsigned)sizeof(void *) ) ;

   return 0 ;
}
```

Provided your build system is consistent, where everything is built with the same options, this builds in implicit portability, and you deal with the problems in your `ifdef`s where you've got `sizeof(long)` wrong on 64-bit ia64 and x64 windows (even with the gcc compiler which you've assumed to mean non-windows).

Backing this up with the static asserts mentioned in a different answer would then give you the best of both worlds.

Comment: Great idea - I can even keep my minimalistic homebrew build system!

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing a lot of cross-platform/cross-compiler work then it may be worth adding static asserts for those constants so you can at least catch platform/compiler combinations that are not set in your ifdefs.

In C++ with boost:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(void*) == SIZEOF_VOIDP)
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(long)  == SIZEOF_LONG)
```

If you're working in C there are a couple of questions on here about implementing static assertions in C.

Macs use a customised version of GCC, so many of the constants you use for GCC should also work on the Mac. I typically detect OSX builds with

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#endif
```

but I'm not sure if this is the best way. On my (32-bit) 10.4 OSX install both a long and void* occupy 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

All those defines look pretty reduntant to me. Just use `sizeof(void*)` and friends.

If you need to have your constants defined, define them like

```
#define SIZEOF_VOIDP sizeof(void*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use sizeof operator?

```
sizeof(long);
sizeof(int);
sizeof(void*);
```

Comment: I need to comply with legacy code that looks like #ifdef SIZEOF_LONG == SIZEOF_VOIDP...

Comment: You could define those macros like #define SIZEOF_LONG (sizeof(long)), and they will always be right.

Comment: The precompiler (at least msvc's) won't allow them in #if statements.

Answer (score 1):

Beware! On Windows, whether you are `i386` (i.e. `x86_32`) or `x86_64`, you will have `sizeof(long) == 4` ! (Or `#define SIZEOF_LONG  4`). Whereas `sizeof(void *) == 8` !

`sizeof(long) != sizeof(void *)`

Comment: Does that apply to IA64 as well? Do you know if IA64 and x64 holds any differences from a C programmer's perspective?

Comment: @Jonas: I don't know. I've never programmed, be it have access to an IA64 system.

Comment: More info on ILP64, LP64, and LLP64 there: http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html

Answer (score 1):

One point to consider about `#define SIZEOF_LONG  8` and `#define SIZEOF_VOIDP 8`.

On HP-UX IA64 this program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
#if defined(__ia64__) && defined(__GNUG__)
    std::cout << sizeof(long) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(void*) << std::endl;
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

if compiled like this:

```
g++ -mlp64 main.cpp
```

gives: 
8 
8

but if compiled like this:

```
g++ -milp32 main.cpp
```

gives 
4
4

Comment: Hum, do you get some type of #define to identify which mode you've compiled with?

Comment: As far as I know `__LP64__` and `_LP64` are defined in `-mlp64` mode.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not complete.

Only `sizeof (char)` is the same on all platforms, compiler options, ...
All other types are not guaranteed to be the same, to stay the same after compiling with different options, ...

You need

```
sizeof (short)
sizeof (int)
sizeof (long)
sizeof (long long) // C99
sizeof (float)
sizeof (double)
sizeof (long double) // C99
sizeof (void *)
sizeof (char *)
sizeof (long double *) // C99

...
```

Comment: Only interested in architectures, don't need the actual contents.

Answer (score 0):

//may be this helps to understand

//with MSC or BORLAND it was possible to do this

```
#if(sizeof(int) == 4)
    typedef int32  int;
#endif

#if(sizeof(int) == 8)
    typedef int64  int;
#endif
```

the GNU Compiler don't resolve this `#if(sizeof(int) == 4)`
he quit this with error message!